# Find a polynomial of degree n that has coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, and is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

I am trying to find a polynomial that has degree n, where n is a natural number, and has also coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, and which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. All I have done so far is say that for an equation such as $x^n+p$ where p is prime, the coefficients are in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ since it is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}$ by the Eisenstein Criterion and is also irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ since  $\sqrt[n]{pi}$ $\notin$ $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. Is this actually the minimal polynomial? If yes, then is my method correct?

Comment: Note that $(1+i)^2=2i$, i.e., for $n=p=2$, you cannot use "since $\sqrt[n]{pi}\notin\Bbb Q(i)$"

Comment: Yes, I see... So does that make my whole proof a false statement?

Comment: For $n$ odd $x^n\pm p$ irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ (not over $\Bbb{R}$...) implies that it stays irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ (because $[\Bbb{Q}(i):\Bbb{Q}]$ is coprime with $n$)

Comment: I understand, but the thing is, I have to find the polynomial for n $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$, and not specifically for n odd

Comment: With mathjax, you don't want to convert each symbol separately. Instead of `$\sqrt[n]{pi}$ $\notin$ $\mathbb{Q}(i)$`, use `$\sqrt[n]{pi} \notin  \mathbb{Q}(i)$`. This not only saves effort on your part, it allows the LaTeX editor to better format the formula. (As a shortcut, you can also use `\Bbb Q` instead of `$\mathbb{Q}$`.)